# Hi! I have an issue: Shopify instagram sales channel

Tags: facebook, instagram, shopify

I have an issue: Shopify instagram sales channel it says

> You need an Instagram business profile to tag products
>
> Switch to a business profile from the Instagram section of your
>   Facebook Page settings.

But my instagram account is already a business accunt, everything is connected, mi pixel, mi facebook manager, my instagram.
Please anybody can help me?

Comment: Hey @sandeep kumar, this looks like a support question that either your dev team or Shopify should be able to help. I will strongly suggest for you to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I actually had the same issue.

Disconnecting both the instagram and the facebook account for 3-4 days, did the trick.